# not receiving ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

[alert Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpdRP.png)

My PHP is not receiving ajax data that is sent when I change a value of an input is it because of that my PHP runs before my script(index.html includes test.js) if so how can resolve the problem or is it something else that I am missing?

PHP and HTML are in the same file because I need to use the values in the PHP

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = "";
    var begin = "";
    var eind = "";
    var aantal = "";

    $('#datum').change(function() {
        date = $("#datum").val();
        console.log(date);
    });
    $('#beginTijd').change(function() {
        begin = ($(this).val());
        console.log(begin);
    });
    $('#Tijdsduur').change(function() {
        eind = ($(this).val());
        console.log(eind);
    });
    $('#aantalSloepen').change(function() {
        aantal = ($(this).val());
        console.log(aantal);

        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                date: begin,
                quantity: aantal
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(begin, aantal);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <script src="test.js"></script>
      <title>reserveren</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="BeschikbaarheidReserveren">
        <hr id="hrOne"><hr id="hrTwo"><hr class="hrActive" id="hrThree"><br>
        <h3>Beschikbaarheid &#38; Reserveren</h3>
        <div id="tableHeader">
          <img src="images/GJ_arrow-left.png" alt="left arrow">
          <img src="images/GJ_arrow-right.png" alt="right arrow">
          <h2 id="vestiging">Utrecht</h2>
        </div>
        <img id="gif" src="http://moziru.com/images/pointer-clipart-animated-gif-7.gif" alt="">
        <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-th-table-wrapper">
    <!-- fixed-th-table -->
    <table>
        <tr>
             <th class="TableGreenJoyGreen"></th>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">9u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">10u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">11u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">12u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">13u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">14u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">15u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">16u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">17u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">18u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">19u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">20u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">21u</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <th>Ma, 26/02/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
             <th>Di, 27/02/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
             <th>Wo, 28/02/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
             <th>Do, 01/03/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
             <th>Vr, 02/03/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
             <th>Za, 03/03/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
             <th>Zo, 04/03/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div class="scrolled-td-table-wrapper">
    <!-- scrolled-td-table
         - same as fixed-th-table -->
    <table>
        <tr>
             <th class="TableGreenJoyGreen"></th>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen"> 9u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">10u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">11u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">12u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">13u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">14u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">15u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">16u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">17u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">18u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">19u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">20u</td>
             <td class="TableGreenJoyGreen">21u</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <th>Ma, 26/02/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
             <th>Di, 27/02/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
             <th>Wo, 28/02/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
             <th>Do, 29/02/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <th>Vr, 01/03/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <th>Za, 02/03/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <th>Zo, 03/03/2018</th>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="fp1"><div class="circleBase type1"></div><p>Beschikbaar</p></div>
        <div id="fp2"><div class="circleBase type2"></div><p>Enkelen beschikbaar</p></div>
        <div id="fp3"><div class="circleBase type3"></div><p>Uitverkocht</p></div>
        <div id="fp4"><div class="circleBase type4"></div><p>Niet beschikbaar</p></div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <form action="betalen.php" method="post" id="form1">
       <label for="date">Datum*</label>
      <span>
      <input name="datum" type="date" id="datum" required>
      </span>
      <br>

      <label for="beginTijd">BeginTijd*</label>
      <span>
      <select name="beginTijd" id="beginTijd" required>
      <option value="09:00">9u</option>
      <option value="10:00">10u</option>
      <option value="11:00">11u</option>
      <option value="12:00">12u</option>
      <option value="13:00">13u</option>
      <option value="14:00">14u</option>
      <option value="15:00">15u</option>
      <option value="16:00">16u</option>
      <option value="17:00">17u</option>
      <option value="18:00">18u</option>
      <option value="19:00">19u</option>
      <option value="20:00">20u</option>
      <option value="21:00">21u</option>
    </select></span><br>


    <label for="">Tijdsduur*</label>
    <span>
    <select name="Tijdsduur" id="Tijdsduur" required>
      <option value="2:00">2 uur varen</option>
      <option value="3:00">3 uur varen</option>
      <option value="4:00">4 uur varen</option>
      <option value="5:00">5 uur varen</option>
      <option value="6:00">6 uur varen</option>
      <option value="9:00">gehele dag varen (9.00-18.00)</option>
      <option value="12:00">gehele dag varen + avond (9.00-22.00)</option>
    </select></span><br>


    <label for="">Aantal sloepen*</label>
    <span>
    <select name="aantalSloepen" id="aantalSloepen" required>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select></span><br>
    <label for="">Aantal personen per sloep*</label>
    <span>
    <select name="aantalPersonenPerSloep" id="aantalPersonenPerSloepSelect" required>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Persoon per sloep Info" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Aantal personen (per sloep), NB: maximaal 540KG aan balast in totaal.">
      <img src="images/info-alt.svg" alt="info">
    </a>
    </span><br>
    <label for="">Vouchercode*</label>
    <span>
    <input name="VoucherCode" type="text">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Vouchercode Info" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Heeft u een voucher of kortingscode ? Voer deze hier in
    Heeft u een kadobon of huurtegoed vul hier dan niets in. Zodra u het email adres onderin invult wordt de kadobon/tegoed verrekend">
    <img src="images/info-alt.svg" alt="info">
    </a>
    </span>
    <br>
    <label class="containerTest">Ik ga akkoord met de 
      <a href="http://greenjoy.nl/algemene-voorwaarden/">algemene voorwaarden</a>*    
      <input name="algemevoorwaardenCheckbox" type="checkbox" required>
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <br><br>
    <label class="containerTest">Borgsom €150.00 - verplicht*
      <input name="borgCheckbox" type="checkbox">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Borg Info" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="De borg bedraagt 150 euro. Je ontvangt deze, als er geen schade is geconstateerd, na het varen weer retour per bank.">
      <img src="images/info-alt.svg" alt="info">
    </a>
      <br><br>
    <label class="containerTest">aanmelden nieuwsbrief en aanbiedingen (2,50 extra korting)
      <input name="nieuwsbriefCheckbox" type="checkbox">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <br   />
    <p>Verplicht veld*</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="form1">

    </form>

    <button id="submitButton" type="submit" form="form1">Volgende ></button>
    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['date'])) {
        echo "Yes, mail is set";    
        $value1= $_POST['date'];  
        $value2= $_POST['quantity'];     
    }else{  
        echo "No, mail is not set";
    }
    echo $value1; 
    echo $value2;
    $canmakereservation = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=can_make_reservation&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556&start_time=2018-04-25 09:00&end_time=2018-04-25 12:00&quantity=5";
            $cleancanmakereservation = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $canmakereservation);
            $reservationavailable = file_get_contents("$cleancanmakereservation");
            $reservationAvailable = json_decode($reservationavailable, true);
            // echo "$cleancanmakereservation";
            // var_dump($reservationAvailable);
    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <h3>Uw huurprijs exlusief borg: € 240,00</h3>
      <p>Dit is momenteel de laagste prijs.<br>
          - Langer varen = meer voordeel <br>
          - Vertrek voor 11.00u en na 17.00u = extra voordeel
      </p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is `aantalSloepen`

Comment: a select i guess

Comment: the name of a html select (number of boats)

Comment: Show your HTML. If `aantalSloepen` is name , your jquery change function never called. as you specify ID selector in it

Comment: `aantalSloepen` must have an id....

Comment: @mauro First you have to check "begin" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution - 1**

Sometime you have to use Jquery's On method see here : [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp) So your code should be something below

```
$('#aantalSloepen').on("change",function() {
    aantal = ($(this).val());
    console.log(aantal);

    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            date: begin,
            quantity: aantal
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(begin, aantal);
        }
    });
});
```

antoher solution Check Your Ajax is working proper when user change the input value so for this you can add alert to check whether it's working or not ...

Solution - 1 
**Try this ajax code with alert**

```
$('#aantalSloepen').change(function() {
    aantal = ($(this).val());
    console.log(aantal);
    alert(aantal);
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            date: begin,
            quantity: aantal
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(begin, aantal);
        }
    });
});
```

Now it will display alert when user change the value

Solution - 2 : **Check browser's Developer Tools**

Open Developer Tool By Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
Now Click On Network tab
[image: See Image Here]
Now Change the Value of input box it should display your index.php if yes your ajax working properly if not then your ajax has error

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the second example with code I get the alert wich means there is nothing wrong with my ajax right?

Comment: right, Now in Ajax On Success Function Try to alert "data" that is returned from index.php

Comment: okay, now can you add picture of your alert that run in ajax success function ?? bcz sometime it return error in php so we determine that this is php code

Comment: A picture of the alert in my browser or a picure of the ajax code in succes funtion?

Comment: a picture of your alert

Comment: I have eddited my post on the top there is an image

Comment: add whole alert or send me

Comment: ok nice! now I know what the problem is. But do you know how to fix it maybe? I can upload the whole index.php file if that helps.

Comment: send me error i will help you if i can ... no don't upload index.php it's already uploaded but upload your error that u recieve with alert copy-paste whole alert text

Comment: you haven't start <?php ?> tag in index.php

Comment: Undefined variable: value1 and Undefined variable: value2 these are the errors I get

Comment: you have declared variable value1 and 2 inside if statement so the variable is useable inside if statement try to declare outside the if statement

Comment: I have started <?php didn't had it in the example

Comment: when I declare the var value1 and value2 outside the if statement the error goes away but the alert says the same and the php if statement echo's No, mail is not set.

Comment: now here is your php code logic mistake try to set in proper your peroblem ajax not working is solved

Comment: sorry I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: in ajax you have set begin = "" null/empty and in ajax you are assigning that value means empty valueto date variable and in php you are checking that variable if it is emplty or not

Comment: try this in if condition your index.php code <?php if(isset($_POST['date']) {  your code }   )?>

Comment: I have given the variables in ajax values and used your if statement but the alert and php if statement gave the same returns